ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC & Identity : error when mocking, System.NotSupportedException: The default UI requires a user store with email support
I am creating unit tests using Moq to achieve 100% coverage for a class auto-generated by Microsoft Scaffold Identity, specifically Register.cs.cshtml. However, I’m encountering this error in some of my tests:

System.NotSupportedException : The default UI requires a user store with email support

Below are snippets of

the log error,
how I am setting the mock test,
how my I configured the Microsoft Identity properties (Program.cs),
the parameters of the RegisterModel, which is the class I need to test and
the GetEmailStore() method where the error is happening.

The log error:

Error Message:
System.NotSupportedException : The default UI requires a user store with email support.
Stack Trace:
at EAM.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel.GetEmailStore() in /home/ygorgsena/eam/Main/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs:line 219
at EAM.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel..ctor(SignInManager`1 signInManager, UserManager`1 userManager, IUserStore`1 userStore, ILogger`1 logger, IEmailSender emailSender) in /home/ygorgsena/eam/Main/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs:line 44
at EAM.Tests.Unit.RegisterUnitTest..ctor() in /home/ygorgsena/eam/Tests/Unit/RegisterUnitTest.cs:line 91
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)

How I am setting up the mock:
public class RegisterModelTests
{
    private readonly Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>> _userManagerMock;
    private readonly Mock<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> _signInManagerMock;
    private readonly Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>> _userStoreMock;
    private readonly Mock<IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>> _emailStoreMock;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<RegisterModel>> _loggerMock;
    private readonly Mock<IEmailSender> _emailSenderMock;
    private readonly RegisterModel _pageModel;

    public RegisterModelTests()
    {
        _userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>();

        _userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(
            _userStoreMock.Object,
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>().Object,
            Array.Empty<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>>(),
            Array.Empty<IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>>(),
            new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
            new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
            new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object);

        _signInManagerMock = new Mock<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>(
            _userManagerMock.Object,
            new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().Object,
            new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>>().Object,
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object,
            new Mock<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object,
            new Mock<IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser>>().Object);

        _emailStoreMock = _userStoreMock.As<IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>>();
        _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<RegisterModel>>();
        _emailSenderMock = new Mock<IEmailSender>();

        _pageModel = new RegisterModel(
            _userManagerMock.Object, _userStoreMock.Object, _signInManagerMock.Object, _loggerMock.Object, _emailSenderMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetEmailStore_ThrowsNotSupportedException_WhenUserManagerDoesNotSupportEmail()
    {
        // Arrange
        _ = _userManagerMock.Setup(m => m.SupportsUserEmail).Returns(false);

        // Use reflection to access the private GetEmailStore method
        MethodInfo? methodInfo = typeof(RegisterModel).GetMethod("GetEmailStore", BindingFlags.NonPublic |                       BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Act & Assert
        Assert.NotNull(methodInfo);
        _ = Assert.Throws<NotSupportedException>(() => methodInfo.Invoke(_pageModel, null));
    }

How my I configured the Microsoft Identity properties in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<EAMContext>();

The parameters of the RegisterModel class:
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
    private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        IUserStore<IdentityUser> userStore,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _userStore = userStore;
        _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

I tried to look at the source code to understand how the IUserEmailStore<TUser> works. The code is located at this link. This GetEmailStore() method is where the error is happening.
private IUserEmailStore<TUser> GetEmailStore()
{
    if (Store is not IUserEmailStore<TUser> emailStore)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.StoreNotIUserEmailStore);
    }

    return emailStore;
}

The Store field defined there at line 139 and is of type
protected internal IUserStore<TUser> Store { get; set; }

The GetEmailStore() method accesses an attribute of type IUserStore and checks if IUserEmailStore is there.
As you can see in the "How I am setting the mock" section, I tried mocking the IUserStore first and then the IUserEmailStore, but it doesn't seem to work.
Despite multiple attempts to resolve this, I’m still running into issues. I would really appreciate any help or insights on properly configuring the mock to include email support for testing. Thank you!

"to achieve 100% coverage" - you do know that achieving "100% code-coverage" from tests is usually counterproductive, right?

I completely agree with you, @Dai, but I was asked to do this regardless of the same arguments you provided.

Inside GetEmailStore you access the Store property - what/where is this Store property defined? How is it populated? Do you understand why your expression inside if (Store is not IUserEmailStore<TUser> emailStore) works the way it does?

@Dai, this GetEmailStore() method is a snippet from Microsoft source code on GitHub. The Store property is defined at line 139 as protected internal IUserStore<TUser> Store { get; set; }. I tried mocking the IUserStore first and then the IUserEmailStore as shown in the "How I am setting the mock" section, but it doesn't seem to work. The method accesses an attribute of type IUserStore and checks if IUserEmailStore is there.

You need to edit your post so that you're including all relevant code. We can't help you when the problematic code is something you've copied-and-pasted from another repo with no details provided...

Edited the post to include further information about the section 5, thanks so far, @Dai

Please look here

@DimiTakis How is that relevant? It's a bug-report about Roslyn code-interceptors and GeneratedRouteBuilderExtensions - but there's nothing in the OP's post that concerns that.

Answering my own question in case someone else has the same problem in the future:
In the code provided, even though we extend the IUserStore to IEmailUserStore when mocking, we still need to manually set the boolean value that enables email support for DefaultUI in _userManagerMock before passing it as a parameter to _signInManager:
_ = _userManagerMock.Setup(x => x.SupportsUserEmail)
    .Returns(true);

